# Freezing a layer partially in a neural net

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to train a neural net with some parameters fixed in a layer.

I have a layer with 30 input and 30 output then it will have 930 parameters/weights if it is a normal dense layer. But I want to fix around 800 of these parameters to zero and don't want them to train. While rest 130 are supposed to be trained.

**Is there a way to freeze some parameters in tensorflow or pytorch?**

P.S. - **Not freezing the whole layer, only partially**.

Comment: If you want to fix them to always be zero, create a mask and use it to zero the desired weights before calling the layer.

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, what you can do is to copy the parameters of a layer, and then after 'optimizer.step()' just copy the parameters back into the layer, effectively resetting the weights.
You could do something like:

```
layer_to_freeze = 0 # change as you need
for i, param in enumerate(model.parameters()): # iteration needed since model.parameters() returns a generator.
    if i == layer_to_freeze: # First layer
        frozen_params = param
optimizer.step() # Backpropagate the gradients.
for i, param in enumerate(model.parameters()):
    if i == layer_to_freeze: # First layer
        with torch.no_grad(): # required for the copying operation
            param[0:30,0:27] = frozen_params[0:30,0:27] # copies 810 parameters, modify according to your desires.
```